# How create slider by model in django?

Tags: jquery, python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

In my Django project I have Slider model. Can someone help me create a slider by this model? I am a little bit confused and need some ideas. I would be grateful for any help.

**models.py:**

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    head = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        help_text='Header',
        blank=False
    )

    body = models.TextField(
        help_text='Description',
        blank=False
    )

    idx = models.IntegerField(
        help_text='Field to sort',
        default=0,
        blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['idx', 'pk']
```

Comment: A slider? Do you mean a carousel? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel I guess you want to create a Carousel with Slides. Remember to make all your models always singular (Slider > Slide). You need a `Carousel(models.Model)` and a `Slide(models.Model)`. The Slide points to a Carousel with a foreignkey field `carousel = models.ForeignKey(Carousel)`.

Comment: Yes, I need something like carousel but with 3 objects in one page and user can move carousel. In this case there must be lazy loading. Move to one point. I hope you understand me. Can you show me some example with code pls. I am little bit confused.

Comment: In the Django tutorial a Answer belongs to a Question. In the same way your Slide belongs to a Carousel. Do the tutorial and learn about related objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Your model slider need a field for the image and a foreign key to a model Carousel that holds all the n images. So when you shows a Carousel you have n slider with its images and texts each one.

```
class Slider(models.Model):
   imagen=models.ImageField()
   carousel=models.ForeignKey(models.Carousel)
   head=...
   body=...
```

Comment: In my model I don't need image field. Its not slider of images. Its slider of blocks with information. I hope you understand me. Slider of words.

Comment: then don't add image field. You only need fk field.

Comment: Well I don't have image field but I steal don't understand what you mean. Can you say your idea more clearly pls.

Comment: You need a model (Carousel) that contains, via FK in Slider model, all items that you need in a Carousel.